# Google App Engine retrieve user defined key name

Tags: google-app-engine, key

Is there a way to retrieve the key name you set using:

```
Model(
  key_name = ...
  ...
)
```

I tried using the key() method but that returns the one Google makes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is key().name()

[Docs on the Key class](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the solution in my case of NDB datastore. check [NDB Key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Key_string_id) link.

With NDB model, you have to use model.key.string_id()